# UIStoryboard Couldn't find view controller with identifier

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have an ios application using storyboards with a bunch of view controllers.

After Adding a new ViewController, and configured the identify (Storyboard ID)
[image]

I try to instantiate the new ViewController with the following code:

```
SurveyNewViewController *newSurvey = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newSurveyView"];
[self presentViewController:newSurvey animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Everything seems to be right, but when running the application on the simulator it crashes:

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:   
'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0xa340fa0>) doesn't contain a view controller 
with identifier 'newSurveyView''
```

Is there any possible explanation for this? I have used this same approach in different places on the system and it works well.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 storyboard?

Comment: Also, what do you do in your `[self storyboard]` method?

Comment: yes @rdelmar, I have more than one storyboard.
@micantox `[self storyboard]` is a property from UIViewController.

Comment: Is SurveyNewViewController in the same storyboard as the controller you have this code in?

Comment: @rdelmar yes, same storyboard.

Comment: Well, I can't see anything wrong then. Try doing a clean on the project. Maybe close Xcode and reopen.

Comment: @rdelmar looks like this fixed. Cleaned the project, removed it from the simulador and running made it work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try remove your app from iPhone Simulator, clean project and build, after run your project.

Comment: remove? ask user to remove too?

Comment: OMG, this one really helps. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: What will happen when existing users get the update?

Answer (score 4):

Try with that :

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardNameOfnewSurveyView" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newSurveyView"];
```

If it works, I think [self storyboard] don't give you the right object ;).

Comment: Tried that already and results is the same. Indeed I have other piece of code, like that one, in the same class that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Set `Storyboard ID` as this is use in Xcode 8.0 and check the `Use Storyboard ID` option. Also check the Class field is set in `Storyboard` to that `ViewController`.

[image: Screenshot of dialogue]