# StoryBoard can not find ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm developing a small app just to learn iOS, and I'm stucked in a situation with the StoryBoard and a ViewController which apparently exists, but when I run the app the compiler throws me a *NSInvalidArgumentException*.

The error is the following one:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'recivedPushViewController''*

As you can see in the following picture, the StoryboardID has been set up

[image: Identity Inspector]

The code which calls the ViewController is the following:

```
        UIViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"recivedPushViewController"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:TRUE completion:NULL];
```

Can anyone help me??

Thank you so much

Comment: See answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007882/uistoryboard-couldnt-find-view-controller-with-identifier

Comment: Make sure only one storyboard you have or not.It's look like identifier name also looking good no issue with that.Try to clean the build and run.

Comment: @Milena i've tried this solution, but the result is the same...

Comment: @KathiravanG there's just one storyboard which contains all the ViewControllers, i've cleaned and run the project few times... :(

Comment: Have you tried to "Reset Content and Settings" and tried again?

Answer (score 1):

Two questions:

- Is this a universal app?
- Does it have 2 StoryBoards?

Are you sure you are adding ViewController to both of the storyboards? It can be a silly mistake while you are adding VC to iPhone StoryBoard only and running iPad app or viceversa.

Comment: There's just 1 storyboard, and it's not an universal app, its an iphone app. :(

Answer (score 1):

Well ladies and gentleman... **I've removed the app from iPhone Simulator,I've cleaned project and built it again,all this before run it**. IT WORKS.

To be honest... I don't understand anything.

Thank you so much for wasting your time in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You mapping your view controller class to RecivedPushViewController.
Try This

```
RecivedPushViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"recivedPushViewController"];
                vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
                [self presentViewController:vc animated:TRUE completion:NULL];
```

Comment: The result is exactly the same... :'(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting the right storyboard? Use:

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

To get the main storyboard