# Passing data to local html iOS webview

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

i'm trying to pass from my view controller after Facebook login to my tab bar view controller, but it gives me this error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'dashBoardViewController''

this is the method :

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSString *userName = [user first_name];
    NSString *userId = [user id];


    dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController =     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**EDITS**

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  LoginSampleFB
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "dashBoardViewController.h"
#import "BFPaperTabBarController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>


@interface ViewController ()



@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"publish_actions",];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSString *userName = [user first_name];
    NSString *userId = [user id];



    dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];
}



-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


@end
```

and

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  LoginSampleFB
//
//  Created by Gabriel Theodoropoulos on 12/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Appcoda. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "BFPaperTabBarController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *showEvent;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *goQrcode;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *id;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *first_name;


@end
```

**UP PLEASE**

Comment: Have you assigned `dashBoardViewController ` as a `StoryBoard ID` to any of your ViewController in your `Interface Builder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you're logged on Facebook, you declare a new controller `dashBoardViewController` and try to display it as a modal controller.

```
dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];
```

But it doesn't make any sense because you already use as initial controller a `dashBoardViewController`. Furthermore this class `dashBoardViewController` is a child class of UITabBarController, so you can access to it in every `viewcontroller` attached to a tabbar.

See this link to understand how UITabBarController works:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/

See this link to understand what is a presenting view controller :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

To solve your issue, you have to call your current tabbarcontroller, cast it as `dashBoardViewController` and set the facebook parameters.

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSString *userName = [user first_name];
    NSString *userId = [user id];
    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name = userName;
    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id = userId;

}
```

You can access to these variables in another controller like `events` for example by the same way :

```
((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name
((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id
```

You should take a look on some object oriented programming courses to understand how it works. In addition, when you code, try to respect the conventions like Camel Case for variable and Pascal case for class.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look on this stackoverflow topic, it's the same issue.

[UIStoryboard Couldn't find view controller with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007882/uistoryboard-couldnt-find-view-controller-with-identifier)

To resume :

1. Check and be sure to have your controller class and your storyboard id setup in the storyboard. (see image in the topic linked to my answer)

   Custom class | class : dashBoardViewController

   Identity | Storyboard ID : dashBoardViewController
2. If yes and it still doesn't work, try to remove your app from iPhone Simulator or your test device, clean your project, build and run it.
3. If the error is still here:
   try to use `[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"nameofyourstoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"]` instead of `self.storyboard`.
   You will be sure to have the right object like that.
4. Still doesn't work? remove your controller from your storyboard and try to recreate a new one. Sometimes it happens...

Comment: LoginSampleFB[504:8259] Warning: Attempt to present <dashBoardViewController: 0x7aa43c00> on <ViewController: 0x79e67110> whose view is not in the window hierarchy! with this method in consolle log it returns me this @jregnauld

Comment: @Jack_usti Can you put the code of your controller which uses FBLoginViewDelegate?

Comment: @Jack_usti I modified the project from AppCoda that you uses.
I added an UITabbarcontroller and an controller which is displayed after you're logged on Facebook.
I think it might help you to understand where is your issue.
http://expirebox.com/download/c0e73ff71a369fb1643359068bf1b4bc.html
Let me know if it's ok.

Comment: what do i have to change in my project? they are a bit different @jregnauld

Comment: @Jack_usti What are these differences and how is setup your storyboard?

Comment: here is my project http://expirebox.com/download/2729e6c0d00365ac660a53333a58a970.html @jregnauld